# Lucene.Net v4.8.0-beta00007 - Custom StopWord Analyzer - Exception Cannot read from a closed TextReader

Tags: lucene.net

We are trying to convert from v3.0.3 to v4.8.0-beta00007. .Net Framework 4.5.

We previously had a Custom StopWords Analyzer that inherited from Analyzer. After upgrading, there is an abstract method that needs to be implemented named:
TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)

Following the documentation from https://lucenenet.apache.org/download/version-4.html to implement this method, we are getting exception: "Cannot read from a closed TextReader."

Here is our implementation:

```
    protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(_luceneVersion, reader);
        TokenStream ts = analyzer.GetTokenStream(fieldName, reader);
        var tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(_luceneVersion, reader);

        try
        {
            ts.Reset(); // Resets this stream to the beginning. (Required)
            while (ts.IncrementToken())
            {
            }
            ts.End();   // Perform end-of-stream operations, e.g. set the final offset.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            ts.Dispose();
        }
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, ts);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues/246#issuecomment-620808822:

As `CreateComponents()` is a factory method (meaning it is a creational operation), only short-lived dependencies should be disposed there. Since you are disposing the stream first before returning it, it is not in a state where the caller of `CreateComponents()` can utilize it.

To make a customized standard analyzer, the best approach would be to model your new class after the [existing StandardAnalyzer class](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/8cf15f7fd0bb7b22bb2e865895998583d049ab92/src/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common/Analysis/Standard/StandardAnalyzer.cs).

```cs
    public sealed class MyStopwordAnalyzer : StopwordAnalyzerBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An unmodifiable set containing some common English words that are usually not
        /// useful for searching. 
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly CharArraySet STOP_WORDS_SET = LoadEnglishStopWordsSet();

        private static CharArraySet LoadEnglishStopWordsSet() // LUCENENET: Avoid static constructors (see https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/pull/224#issuecomment-469284006)
        {
            IList<string> stopWords = new string[] { "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be",
                "but", "by", "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "no", "not", "of", "on",
                "or", "such", "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these", "they", "this",
                "to", "was", "will", "with" };
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            var stopSet = new CharArraySet(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_CURRENT, stopWords, false);
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
            return CharArraySet.UnmodifiableSet(stopSet);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds an analyzer with the given stop words. </summary>
        /// <param name="matchVersion"> Lucene compatibility version - See <see cref="MyStopwordAnalyzer"/> </param>
        /// <param name="stopWords"> stop words  </param>
        public MyStopwordAnalyzer(LuceneVersion matchVersion, CharArraySet stopWords)
            : base(matchVersion, stopWords)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds an analyzer with the default stop words (<see cref="STOP_WORDS_SET"/>). </summary>
        /// <param name="matchVersion"> Lucene compatibility version - See <see cref="MyStopwordAnalyzer"/> </param>
        public MyStopwordAnalyzer(LuceneVersion matchVersion)
            : this(matchVersion, STOP_WORDS_SET)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds an analyzer with the stop words from the given reader. </summary>
        /// <seealso cref="WordlistLoader.GetWordSet(TextReader, LuceneVersion)"/>
        /// <param name="matchVersion"> Lucene compatibility version - See <see cref="MyStopwordAnalyzer"/> </param>
        /// <param name="stopwords"> <see cref="TextReader"/> to read stop words from  </param>
        public MyStopwordAnalyzer(LuceneVersion matchVersion, TextReader stopwords)
            : this(matchVersion, LoadStopwordSet(stopwords, matchVersion))
        {
        }

        protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
        {
            var src = new StandardTokenizer(m_matchVersion, reader);
            TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(m_matchVersion, src);
            // tok = new LowerCaseFilter(m_matchVersion, tok); // optional
            tok = new StopFilter(m_matchVersion, tok, m_stopwords);
            return new TokenStreamComponents(src, tok);
        }
    }
```

Do note that the existing `StandardAnalyzer` class also allows passing in a `CharArraySet` containing stopwords, which may meet your needs if you wish to use the `LowerCaseFilter` to normalize your text.